# How to check the input element is inside form element or not

Tags: java, jsoup

HTML Code:-

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return false" action="/riskAuth/bharosaSMLogin.jsp" name="loginForm">
<---Some HTML code inside form tag --->
<input type="HIDDEN" name="ssobrand">
<---Some HTML code inside form tag--->
</form>
<---Some HTML code outside form tag --->
<input type="hidden" value="advisor" name="appId">
<---Some HTML code outside form tag--->
```

Java Code :-

```
Elements formElements =  doc.getElementsByTag("input");
for(Element formElem : formElements){
    /*Code required to check whether input element is inside form element*/
}
```

I want to get the input elements which are not inside the form element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the CSS selector and the :not pseudo selector.

```
Elements formElements = doc.select("input:not(form input)");
```

See documentation at http://jsoup.org/apidocs/index.html?org/jsoup/select/Selector.html